# Prove that $A=\emptyset$ iff the equality $\bigl(((U \backslash A) \cap B) \cup (A \cap (U \backslash B))\bigr)=B$ holds.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $A$, $B$ and $U$ be sets such that  $A \subseteq U$ and $B \subseteq U$.

Prove that $A=\emptyset$ iff the equality $\bigl(((U \backslash A) \cap B) \cup (A \cap (U \backslash B))\bigr)=B$ holds.

---

Given $A \subseteq U$, i.e. $\forall x, x \in A \implies x \in U$
and $B \subseteq U$, i.e. $\forall x, x \in B \implies x \in U$,

Prove $A=\emptyset$ iff the equality $\bigl(((U \backslash A) \cap B) \cup (A \cap (U \backslash B))\bigr)=B$

Prove ($\implies$):

Suppose $A = \emptyset$, i.e. $\forall x, x \not \in A$

$\bigl(((U \backslash A) \cap B) \cup (A \cap (U \backslash B))\bigr)\\
i.e. \bigl(((\forall x, x \in U, x \not \in A) \land (x \in B)) \cup ((x \in A) \land (\forall x, x \in U, x \not \in B))\bigr)\\ $

---

I know that since $A = \emptyset$, the right side of the union is automatically false. However, I have no idea how I am supposed to proceed. Please guide in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$\bigl(((U \backslash A) \cap B) \cup (A \cap (U \backslash B))\bigr) = \big(U\cap A^c\cap B\big) \cup\big(A\cap U\cap B^c\big) = (A^c\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^c).$$

Answer (score 1):

For the $\Rightarrow$ direction, instead of starting to look at individual element, it is easier just to work at the set algebra level: When $A=\varnothing$ plug it into the left-hand side to get
$$ ((U\setminus \varnothing)\cap B) \cup (\varnothing\cap(U\setminus B)) =
(U\cap B)\cup \varnothing =
U \cap B $$
which is $B$ becasue $B\subseteq U$.

For the $\Leftarrow$ direction, the easiest way appears to prove the contraposed form:

> If $A\ne \varnothing$ then $((U\setminus A)\cap B) \cup (A\cap(U\setminus B))\ne B$.

For this you *would* start by looking at an element $x\in A$ (and you're assuming exactly that such an element exists). Then split into cases based on whether $x\in B$ or $x\notin B$.

---

Your proposed proof start is, I'm afraid to say, misusing notation quite a bit. When you write

> $\bigl(((\forall \color{blue}x, \color{blue}x \in U, \color{blue}x \not \in A) \land (\color{red}x \in B)) \cup ((\color{red}x \in A) \land (\forall \color{green}x, \color{green}x \in U, \color{green}x \not \in B))\bigr)$

Given the context I can see that you've probably tried to translate the *set* expression $((U\setminus A)\cap B) \cup (A\cap(U\setminus B))\ne B$ into a logical statement about *elements*, but you have done it only halfway and arrived at something ill-formed that definitely doesn't express what you want to say.

**First**, you're mixing up notation for *sets* (the $\cup$ must come between sets) with notation for *propositions* (the $\land$ creates a proposition).

**Second**, the two occurrences of $x$ I've marked in red are not in the scope of any quantifier, whereas the blue and green ones are.

**Third**, where do you have quantifiers, you're writing some commas whose meaning can only be understood if one already has an idea what you're probably trying to say.

Comment: Ohhh. How would you suggest I edit the notation?

Comment: @kevinbobbkoh: What you're trying to do is say something like $$ x\in \bigl( ((U\setminus B)\cap B)\cup(A\cap(U\setminus B))\bigr) \iff \\ \bigl( ((x\in U \land x\notin A)\land x\in B)\lor(x\in A\land(x\in U\land x\notin B))\bigr) $$ but I doubt that actually represents progress for you here. Instead of manipulating symbolic formulas (that it looks like you only have a somewhat shaky understanding of) you should try to _understand_ the problem well enough that you can give an argument in _ordinary words_, and only afterwards (if at all!) try to express it in symbols.

Comment: If you don't mind, could I get you to explain how the question should be done? I'd really really appreciate the effort, and I really really need the help (evidently).

Comment: @kevinbobbkoh: That's what the part of this answer before the vertical line does.

Comment: Horizontal line, that is. Apparently I can't English today.

Comment: Thank you. I really really appreciate the effort. Will try and see whether I can conjure the proof.